# Customize TOC tab leader

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents

In Microsoft Word I can choose between dots `...`, dashes `---` and a line for the tab leader in the table of contents menu. But I want to increase the dots' distance, for example with some spaces between them like `. . .`. How can I do this in Word?

[image: Table of Contents]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this but if you regenerate the TOC you will need to do these steps again:

You can select the tab spaces and using Format -> Font -> Advanced, you can select "Expanded" from the "Spacing" dropdown and then enter the number of points by which you want to increase the spacing between the dots.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it affects the headings too.

Comment: Make sure you only highlight the leader dots, see my animation above for a demonstration.

Comment: It works but there are many headings and subheadings and I need to regenerate the TOC frequently to review my work! Your answer is useful, anyway :)

Comment: Thanks, there's not any other way I can think of to achieve this but I would be very interested to find out if there is.